# Magento 2 custom theme attribute

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

I had created a custom theme and copied the attribute.phtml from the vendor to my custom theme. I am getting an error like this?

> Exception #0 (Exception): Warning:
> include(/var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml):
> failed to open stream: Permission denied in
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php on
> line 71

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I can help you how to edit this core file in your theme, it might be possible that you have made some mistakes while overriding the file path. I tried this thing and it is working well for me, steps are as below ::

step 1:: add your custome theme in the app/design folder

step 2 :: in your theme (Package/Theme) add Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml

step 3:: copy the core file attribute.phtml in your theme and then you can add changes that you want in that file

step 4:: assign that theme from the admin panel (content>Configuration) to your website

and then changes will be reflected in your storefront!

-->>>>if you get your answer or any help, so please mark or make usefull this answer, if you can that would be helpful for me, thank you :)

Comment: Hello, After copying attribute.phtml from the vendor directory to theme directory. This problem occurs for me.

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: include(/var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php on line 71

Comment: have you run the permission command :: 
                         sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/

Comment: No I didn't..because chmod 777 was not recommended to use right?

Comment: the error show permission denied that's why!

Comment: I tried this command also.. sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/! Not working